# How to manually destroy a ReactiveDict?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming

I want to update my structured data partially using a `ReactiveDict` and I have an UI (modal form) depending UI (modal form) on that data.
`ReactiveVar` can't provide me the functionalities I use with `ReactiveDict`.

However I would like to discard a named instance of `ReactiveDict`, to free memory or because I want to reuse its name.

How to remove a named instance of `ReactiveDict` manually without refreshing my page?

Comment: Well .. If I provide some name to its constructor, then I can't create another one with same name(that's normal) until page will be refreshed. And if I'll create ReactiveDict without passing some name to constructor, then ok. But I'm not sure that this will not cause memory problems

Comment: Unfortunately memory allocations are somewhat of a nightmare in JavaScript and even more so in Meteor, where reactive stuff is passed around and computed on and double-referenced everywhere. I think the only thing you can do is `delete` as many things as possible and hope everything goes well.

Answer (score 3):

All named instances of `ReactiveDict`s are stored in `ReactiveDict._dicsToMigrate`.

To remove it, simply `delete ReactiveDict._dicsToMigrate['my dictionary']` and it won't be migrated. Then you can `delete` other references to your variable (object field, ...) and it's done.

You will also need to `stop` all watching computations.

During my tests I also noted that migrated but unused dictionaries are not migrated again. Heh.